# Displaying different view to a differ user based on the value from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, knockout.js, sql-server-2012

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC application which a user can log in and view data retrieved from the database using knockout JS and Odata with two different roles, one can add, edit and delete data and other just read the data.

For example, I have three fields pulled from a SQl table to the web page Company,Product and Price

**Admin View** is as follows

```
    <td data-bind="text: Company"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Product"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Price"></td>
<td class="actioncells">

        <a class="btn btn-success" title="Edit" data-bind="click: $root.edit">Edit</a> 
</td>
<td class="actioncells">

        <a class="btn btn-success" title="Edit" data-bind="click: $root.delete">Del</a> 
</td>
```

**Customer View(Read Only)**

```
 <td data-bind="text: Company"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Product"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Price"></td>
```

**Home Controller**

```
 [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult Admin()
        {

            return View();
        }
```

The above works fine but I have each user associated with a company and I want to display a view such that no matter what role he has but he still should be able to edit and delete data of the company he is associated with. I am not sure how to deal with it and I have the following data in different tables

**UserProfile**

```
UserId UserName
1      demo_admin
2      test
3      sample
```

**Company**

```
Id CName
1  XCorp
2  YCorp
3  ZCorp
```

**UserCompanies**

```
Id  CompanyId UserId
1    2         3
2    3         2
```

**Data_Items**

```
Id  CompanyID  CompanyName Price
1    2          XCorp      100
2    3          ZCorp       58
2    3          ZCorp       75
```

From the above data from different table, I assume user `demo_admin` as `admin` and `test` and `sample` users as customers associated with `ZCorp` and `YCorp` respectively.
So, on the output page when the users login `demo_admin` should be able to `edit` and `delete` all the date where as users `test` and `sample` should be able to `edit` and `delete` `ZCorp` and `YCorp` data respectively and can only view remaining data ie., `XCorp`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that you can achieve this is through two tools,

1. ensure that you secure your edit.. make sure that it required that the user has enough priviliges to edit before allowing edit (don't assume your user won't figure out your uri structure and post naughty requests)
2. use [Knockout templating](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) for example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqtof6ju/

   ```
   <h2>non admin view</h2>
   <div data-bind="template: { name: 'edit-disabled' }"></div>

   <h2>admin view</h2>
   <div data-bind="template: { name: 'edit-enabled' }"></div>


   <script type="text/html" id="edit-enabled">
       <input data-bind="value: data"></input>
   </script>

   <script type="text/html" id="edit-disabled">
       <div data-bind="text: data"></div>
   </script>
   ```

The best way you can achieve your goals is through [Knockout components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html#example-loading-the-likedislike-widget-from-external-files-on-demand). This would be a better approach as you can use things like require.js to load only the stuff you need.. or better yet, if you don't want to use somthing like requrie.js you could just use a razor if statement to change the definition of the component so that it will send down a definition for admin or a definition for a non-admin.

components are cool as it allows you to define something like

```
ko.components.register('like-or-dislike', {
    viewModel: { require: 'files/component-like-widget' },
    template: { require: 'text!files/component-like-widget.html' }
});
```

and then when ever you want to re-use this edit field you simply would use:

```
<like-or-dislike></like-or-dislike>
```

Hope this helps :).

edit:

Maybe this would work better:

```
<h2>Company Data</h2>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'company-data' }"></div>


<!-- if the user is logged in and has write for this company, send this down -->
<script type="text/html" id="edit-enabled">
    <input data-bind="value: data"></input>
</script>
<!-- END -->


<!-- if the user ints logged in or doesnt have write for this company, send this down -->
<script type="text/html" id="edit-disabled">
    <div data-bind="text: data"></div>
</script>
<!-- END -->
```

Comment: Well, the answer you posted is already achieved in my question. I am able to implement authorization for admin and non admin, when a user is logged in first it should look for which company he is associated and then allow him to edit the entries that has his company and can just view other data. This is my question as I already posted

Comment: All you would do is check what company(s) the authorized user has write access to and send down the right form... Maybe you could make the template called company-data instead of enabled,disabled and only pass down the template with write, if the MVC razer view is told to